# Why is causing mariadb service restart?

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

```
lines 72-85
Dec 08 20:50:08 rockpi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.47 database server.
Dec 08 20:50:08 rockpi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 2.229s CPU time
Dec 08 20:50:14 rockpi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 08 20:50:14 rockpi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 08 20:50:14 rockpi systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.1.47 database server.
Dec 08 20:50:14 rockpi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 2.229s CPU time
Dec 08 20:50:14 rockpi systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.1.47 database server...
Dec 08 20:50:17 rockpi sh[22994]: WSREP: Recovered position f5d6fbc2-31ab-11eb-8a0a-736512fe0cbd:11066
Dec 08 20:50:18 rockpi mysqld[23191]: 2020-12-08 20:50:18 547799248912 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.47-MariaDB-0uDec 08 20:50:21 rockpi rsyncd[23266]: rsyncd version 3.1.2 starting, listening on port 4444
Dec 08 20:50:22 rockpi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Dec 08 20:50:22 rockpi rsyncd[23266]: sent 0 bytes  received 0 bytes  total size 0
Dec 08 20:50:22 rockpi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Dec 08 20:50:22 rockpi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.47 database server.
Dec 08 20:50:22 rockpi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 2.326s CPU time
Dec 08 20:50:27 rockpi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 08 20:50:27 rockpi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
```

Comment: did you try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375471/failed-to-start-mariadb-database-server-after-upgrade-to-debian-9

Comment: But i did not updated by ubuntu, mariadb server version did not change.

Comment: did you try it? cause most of the time cleaning all up and reinstalling stuff works

Comment: Well i have taken backup of db , i can try that.

Comment: some times reinstalling doesn't work because we don't know how to clean it all up

Comment: This is galera cluster node.

Comment: MariaDB 10.1 is eoled - time to upgrade!

Comment: @GeorgRichter latest supported version for arm64 I get is 10.1
`$ apt-cache policy mariadb-server
mariadb-server:
  Installed: 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Candidate: 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:10.1.29-6 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe arm64 Packages`